# Limit users on nginx using wildcard

Tags: linux, nginx, sas

I'm starting a work with Nginx to reverse proxy my app for internet access outside my customer's network.

I managed to make it work, limiting the URLs that need to be exposed etc, but one thing is still due to finish my work.

I want to limit user access based on the username. But instead of creating an if for every user I want to block, I would like to use a wildcard because all the users I want to block ends with a specific string: @saspw

Sample of my /etc/nginx/conf.d/reverseproxy.conf

```
server  {
  listen  80;   # Proxy trafic for SAS Visual Analytics Transport Services on HTTP
  server_name  mcdonalds-va-reverseproxy.cons.sashq-r.openstack.sas.com;
  if ($remote_user = '*@saspw'){
      return 401;
  }
  location  /SASVisualAnalyticsTransport {
    proxy_pass  https://mtbis.mcdonalds.com.au:8343/SASVisualAnalyticsTransport/;
  }
}
```

In the $remote_user **if**, I would like that all users with its username ending in @saspw get a 401 error, (which I will change to a 404 later).

It does only work if I put the whole username, like **joe@saspw**. Using a wildcard **(*,?)** does not work.

Is there a way to make $remote_user solve wildcards that way?

Thank you,
Joe

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`map nginx module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html)

```
map $remote_user $is_denied {
    default 0;
    "~.*@saspw" 1;
}

server  {
  listen  80;   # Proxy trafic for SAS Visual Analytics Transport Services on HTTP
  server_name  mcdonalds-va-reverseproxy.cons.sashq-r.openstack.sas.com;
  if ($is_denied){
      return 401;
  }
  location  /SASVisualAnalyticsTransport {
    proxy_pass  https://mtbis.mcdonalds.com.au:8343/SASVisualAnalyticsTransport/;
  }
}
```

It lets you to use regexes. Note that map must be outside `server` directive.

Comment: Awesome, problem solved! Thank you very much, Robert!